# PHP json get specyfic value

Tags: php, json

JSON:

```
{
   "info":true,
   "test1":{
      "test2":{
         "test3":0,
         "test4":1
      }
   }
}
```

PHP code:

```
$json_url = "url";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json,true);

echo $data['test1']["test2"]["test3"];  
echo $data['test1'][0]["test2"]["test3"];   
echo $data['test1']["test2"][0]["test3"];   
echo $data['test1']["test2"][0]["test3"][0];
```

Nothing is displayed on the page, no errors, etc.
I also tried to do foreach but it didn't change anything.

Comment: what is `$json` value as you echo it?

Comment: And then what does `var_dump($data);` show you?